# Customized slider handle snapping to cursor?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I'm using a completely ordinary jQuery slider whose handle I narrowed using the following CSS:

```
html body .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width: 10px;
}
```

This has the desired effect of narrowing the slider handle, but it has the unwanted side effect of making the handle snap to a position just left of the cursor when I try to drag it.

What's causing this, and how can I modify the behavior?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7pW3/1/    Grab the handle and slowly drag it, you'll see that while moving it will always be positioned a bit to the left of the cursor instead of staying where it was relative to the click. The code controlling the dragging needs to be alerted to the width change, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle` uses `margin-left` in the CSS.

When you change the `width`, make sure to also change the `margin-left`.

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: -.3em; /*change this*/
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Z7pW3/6/

Comment: I'm not quite pro enough at CSS to understand why you chose em over px-- can you explain?

Comment: @Aerovistae no worries, this article helped me out: http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/ You will notice most jQueryUI CSS uses `em`.